# Find Sub-matrix with matched cell 1

Tags: code-golf, matrix, restricted-complexity, binary-matrix

You are given a matrix of size m x n where each cell can contain either 1 or 0. You need to find the largest square submatrix that contains only 1's. The output should be the area of the largest square submatrix.

For example, given the following matrix:

```
1 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 0
```

The largest square submatrix that contains only 1's is:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

So the output should be 9 since the area of the square is 3x3 = 9.

The time complexity of your algorithm should be O(mn).

Comment: Output must be 2x2=4

Comment: oh sorry, you right, hang on!

Comment: please check again :,)

Comment: What if there is algorithm with less time complexity? :)

Comment: With your edit, it is evident that the submatrix must be contiguous, but it wouldn't hurt to state this explicitly. (Adding the leftmost column would give a 3-row, 4-column sub-matrix.)

Comment: Can the input matrix be a long one dimensional array or it must be 2 dimensional array?

Comment: @EzioMercer everything is up to you except time complexity :)

Comment: yes, gonna add, plus please pardon me because I am young and new to this site, it might take me some time to be familiar here, adding the new keyword @Arnauld

Comment: Perfect. No worries!

Comment: @EzioMercer Lowest complexity to possibly take input

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 148 bytes

```python
lambda X,o=1:[B:=c(c(pad(X,1),0),1),[o:=o+(B[i,j]+B[i-o,j-o]-B[i,j-o]-B[i-o,j]==o*o)for i,j in argwhere(X)+1]]and~-o*~-o
from numpy import*
c=cumsum
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU9BboMwELzzCh_XsKBQtVWE5AN5AickalUuYEIUey0HlOTSV_TWC1LV_qm_qWly2N3RjEYz-_njrtOe7PKlxcv3POl0-_txVOatU6xGEnnR7ArRQgtOdVBjznHD191QISiBXTPiQSbhpISHlGT6z9zBykkhKCauybMgsNEy5Yfzvvc91DzJpVS2e08pDhNpT4bZ2bgrG40jP8VRK9rZnGZz76a9HZhgPpjIZF2v1XycXgMJPKpWwQ7ZaKd-6P0JNviA8ISP-Mx5tBYo1_i4wioz6gLhkQBGG0ARMeeDD0rUUHJ-S1uW2_0D)

Should be linear in the size N (total number of elements) of the input.

#### How?

Computes first the 2d partial sums B of the input. After this one off O(N) (space and time) investment we can count the number of ones in any grid rectangle in constant time using the four corners of the rectangle: B(top left)+B(bottom right)-B(top right)-B(bottom left).

We can now find the maximum in linear time by traversing the input a single time top left to bottom right. We only check for squares that have their bottom right corner at the current position. If the current point is bottom right of a new maximum square we know that the current maximum must be one less because we have already visited the top left neighbour of the current point. Therefore we need at each point only check a single square, the loop body is constant time and the loop is linear.

Comment: Ah, so for each 1 in the array (going left to right, top to bottom), we check whether a square going top left with size curMax+1 is all 1. Nice idea!

Answer (score 5):

## MATL, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
lYa`9I&ZItz}x@UGaa*
```

*2 bytes saved thanks to @lmendo*

The complexity of the erosion operation is O(mn), but unfortunately with this approach, we perform erosion as many as max(m, n) times.

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=lYa%609I%26ZItz%7Dx%40UGaa%2a&inputs=%5B1+0+1+1+1%3B1+0+1+1+1%3B1+1+1+1+1%3B1+0+0+1+0%5D&version=22.7.4)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a multi-dimensional array
lYa     % Pad with a row of zeros on the top and bottom to ensure erosion works
`       % do...while loop
  9I&ZI % Perform image erosion with a 3 x 3 neighborhood
  t     % Duplicate the output
  z     % Check if there are any 1's left in the eroded result, if so, repeat
}       % End loop
x       % Delete the last element on the stack (the eroded matrix of all 0's)
@       % Get the index of the last loop iteration and
U       % Square it to get the size of the largest contiguous square of 1's
Gaa     % Check if there are any 1's in the input
*       % Multiply with the result (to account for a matrix of all 0's)
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><strike>78 76</strike></sup> 75 bytes

```
[:>./@,@;($<@,:&2@#:i.@#@,)({:*1+<./@}:)@,;.0`(0<@{1+[)`]}&.>/@,&|.0<@,0&,.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BCoJAEIbv@xSjxq6b27TrIXA0GQg6deoqkhBJdekBzGff1k5FyTDMz/fzMXdfROTaTUSFUiJG1cOWQIEBCxR2hbA7Hva@oRrXbLhMFxUbkjkndENO2Oh0oKXLqlCPpNmUaLvUVjy4rNFdO0qsgyifGJix0qDX4nK@PqCHGEs85dBOv6xw4bhpvpL7YBO1YlZ3f6TfNK8L@66FfwE)

\$\mathcal{O}(mn)\$ using a standard dynamic programming table.

The only challenge was how to translate this essentially procedural algorithm into an array paradigm:

- First add a top-left border of zeros:

  ```
   0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 1 0 1 1 1
   0 1 0 1 1 1
   0 1 1 1 1 1
   0 1 0 0 1 0
  ```
- Next generate the coordinates for what would be the nested loop in a procedural language -- that is, we traverse from left to right, top to bottom.   We also add `2 2` to each, since we'll be cutting out 2x2 squares later.  For example, the first element represents the 2x2 square whose top-left coordinate is `0 0`:

  ```
  ┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
  │0 0│0 1│0 2│0 3│0 4│1 0│1 1│1 2│1 3│1 4│2 0│2 1│2 2│2 3│2 4│3 0│3 1│3 2│3 3│3 4│
  │2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│2 2│
  └───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
  ```
- Now we reverse the above list and use it in a single reduction of the input from the previous step.  In each step of the reduction, we slice out a two by two square.  For example in the first step of the reduction we take the top-left square:

  ```
  0 0
  0 1
  ```
- The reduction logic is simple.  Call the value of the lower-right cell `lr`.  We update `lr` as follows: `lr * (1 + min(all values except lr))`.
- Return the max value of the completed dynamic programming table.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>88</s> <s>80</s> 46 bytes

```
≔Ｅθ⁰θＷＳ«≔⮌θη≔⟦⁰⟧θＦι⊞θ×Ｉκ⊕⌊⟦↨υ⁰⊟η↨η⁰⟧⊞υ⌈θ»ＩＸ⌈υ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4/D8IgEMVn@RSMR6IJuDqpk0OTRt2MA6mnEFva8kdNjJ8dr60ywOXx3u9eZbSvWl3nvA7B3hwUuoN@zqWY816s2NPYGjnsXJfiIXrrbiAEf7PZz77HB/qA0JPfkP@vn@R5AsyuredgBS9TMAP5aBsMsNUhwp1CO1d5bNBFvEBhnW1SA6eNJmSaWpRtB4beUTODdhZ0iDwSyVXo1xjrB/XDSmoZpwVl@0QP//9ElOUQzVlJpRT73WqapZIsLx71Fw) Link to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated bit strings. Explanation: Now a port of @Jonah's J solution.

```
≔Ｅθ⁰θ
```

Start with a row of zeros.

```
ＷＳ«
```

Loop over each input row.

```
≔⮌θη
```

Reverse the previous row totals to make them easier to process.

```
≔⟦⁰⟧θ
```

Start collecting a new row with a zero column.

```
Ｆι
```

For each cell...

```
⊞θ×Ｉκ⊕⌊⟦↨υ⁰⊟η↨η⁰⟧
```

... multiply its value with the incremented minimum of the cells above and to the left. The cell above is obtained by popping the reversed previous row, the cell to the above left is obtained as the base `0` of the popped reversed previous row and the cell to the left is obtained as the base `0` of the new row.

```
⊞υ⌈θ
```

Collect the maximum square found in this row.

```
»ＩＸ⌈υ²
```

Output the largest found square from all rows.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 109 bytes

```
Catch[Do[If[AnyTrue[Erosion[ArrayPad[#,1],BoxMatrix[All,n]],#==1&,2],Throw[n]],{n,Min@Dimensions@#,1,-1}]]^2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCoMwEIDhhyk4XcEIjkJs7eAgSHE7Uggaa8Bc4EypIj57Wtcfvt/pMBmng@11HIt416GfsPJYj1jS1vHH4IP9Yj1hyay3Vg94AaHg5tdGB7YrlvMMpBRcikIkkCnoJvZfPNNO0FiSlXWGzsci/xau4lDqlSWxZUtBjvKpafCupmDehlHAnqeQp4eKPw)

Comment: Times out on `Print@f@RandomInteger[1, {200, 200}]` (so probably not O(mn)), also returns answers between 9800 and 10000 for `Print@f@RandomInteger[1, {100, 100}]` so I don't think the logic is correct.

Comment: @Jonah yes, thanks, I fixed the problem with `BoxMatrix` and now the results are always correct. As for the execution time, on the desktop `f@RandomInteger[1, {200, 200}]` takes about 20-30 seconds. But probably `Erosion[]` is not O(mn), i don't know ((

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 20 bytes

```
ɖλZɖλ÷nfṪg›*";vt;fG²
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJls67WsmWzrvDt25m4bmqZ+KAuipcIjt2dDtmR8KyIiwiIiwiW1sxLDAsMSwxLDFdLFsxLDAsMSwxLDFdLFsxLDEsMSwxLDFdLFsxLDAsMCwxLDBdXSJd)

Based on [*@Jonah's* J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257862/116074).

For each 2x2 square

```
a b
c d
```

it replaces `d` with `d*(min(a,b,c)+1)` in sequence going from left to right, top to bottom. Then it takes maximum and squares it.

```
ɖλ                   # scan by:
  Z                  #   zip
   ɖλ                #   scan by:  receives [a,c], [b,d]
     ÷               #     push each to stack
      n              #     push the function argument [[a,c],[b,d]]
       f             #     flatten
        Ṫ            #     remove tail  [a,c,b]
         g           #     minimum
          ›          #     increment
           *         #     multiply
            "        #     pair [b, new d]
             ;       #   end scan
              vt     #   get the tail of each
                ;    # end scan
                 f   # flatten
                  G  # maximum
                   ² # square
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, C++ : <s>231</s> <s>227</s> 196 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to EzioMercer

-31 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

```cpp
int f(int t[],int x,int y){int z=1,j=y,i,v,w,m,k,b;for(;j--;)for(i=x;i--;)if(t[i*y+j]){v=k=1;w=0;for(m=x-i<y-j?x-i:y-j;k++<m;w=v?k:w)for(b=k*k;b--;)v=t[y*(i+b%k)+j+b/k]?v:0;z=w>z?w:z;}return z*z;}
```

[TIO Link](https://tio.run/##jZHdaoQwEIXvfQrZspCYsVXYvTFmfRDrRdW1jamu2PiPz24TrdBuoTSBnDk5kw/CJFVlvybJsvBSmhnSpwwj0Nqv54AnLSNzIWcDcGihgwIExDS71Yjmtk2xrjjrKdeGZ0iG3BpIHuGpZYK5tGPO2l2w3ub@YOeBUk8pFYT4hcrbQHjdyomZsASNNallMhwsxEl8FJjkJH4SUdB6Dh1ZdxmDzhvpXF9lU5fmaKl6eeBl8t6kV/9Dpvz2@HYxtg@do/AUmcycDFOtyYV1z7BZBxxlnd1u6Z1171Njpiu8@Q3/QVvN9@f/SXd48cJLhL/IVa2uMnSo2TF9Lg@gxqXnZWEJZzhhTP/uavauefkE) thanks The Thonnu for pointing it out

Test code :

```cpp
int t[5][4] = {
    {1,1,1,1},
    {0,0,1,0},
    {1,1,1,0},
    {1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,0}
};

int main() {
    printf("r=%d\n", f((int*)t,5,4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can include a [Try it online](https://tio.run/##XVBdb4QgEHz3V9hLmrCyJpjcvRRpf4j1QW1tgGgbQ/0Mv90uen05SBhmZhlgm/SrafZd9y5uWVhdUWLA@VgX2AKsKkOjBGocccIOLdZYyfZ7YNLki@TcQCBaCanzmbgG3TJX6GThpoRtVJmcyOzUnOp8Sc0b4QvhkWHJtXlHxyxsQaiptM6VJaU@gisSqlOoQvKTK5aEaSLc8LqEMVzcshEmZXkmPe2n1xVWNUk/fLrfoY/XZJV@P394K4trGat4i2IaW4bH9HhSgYKo@Ken@0CzRzfyMopCelfpnsE9@mcgqWWXQT1/vPcXpB6HJifg8IZXAHlU3V8oZOT3Pw) link in the answer so others can test your code online.

Comment: @TheThonnu added, thanks

Comment: [227](https://tio.run/##XZDLboMwEEX3fAVNVcnGQ2WkZINx@BDKgkdobQqpqMNTfDsdk3QTW5rrM9e6sqfwP4tie1Vt8X0rL270a0p1ff86b6o1bkVsNUkKVse9TnSxMssAtOSgoIcBGqghh0xU144IHU2CMU0tKMmFikZkRVVFTKK8iemULr0MxIBmI0dfRZOvY9QQdc@o0WGsjhpBF8s5ch7JGpv5npthI7MNm/pikskjimWMUaZZntIe7UH2cc2CcBDrLIfzHA/hLNbuYm5d684enrf7705pckxd6S6Oi2sJYN8r3JEDR@T/eHefMHh2nVU4jk1vMtUS@oj@6bBVkUMn38qP9gA4Xztgjxo4wZFSsd96vJALZ93@AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: [196 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZHdaoQwEIXvfQrZspCYsVXYvTFmfRDrRdW1jamu2PiPz24TrdBuoTSBnDk5kw/CJFVlvybJsvBSmhnSpwwj0Nqv54AnLSNzIWcDcGihgwIExDS71Yjmtk2xrjjrKdeGZ0iG3BpIHuGpZYK5tGPO2l2w3ub@YOeBUk8pFYT4hcrbQHjdyomZsASNNallMhwsxEl8FJjkJH4SUdB6Dh1ZdxmDzhvpXF9lU5fmaKl6eeBl8t6kV/9Dpvz2@HYxtg@do/AUmcycDFOtyYV1z7BZBxxlnd1u6Z1171Njpiu8@Q3/QVvN9@f/SXd48cJLhL/IVa2uMnSo2TF9Lg@gxqXnZWEJZzhhTP/uavauefkE "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 186 bytes

I know that the complexity should be `O(mn)` but here the complexity is `O((mn)^2)` :)

```
m=>eval('for(x=b=0;x<(r=m.length);++x)for(y=0;y<(c=m[0].length);++y)if(m[x][y]){for(o=s=1;o&&s<(c>r?r:c);++s)for(t=s+1;t--;)if(!m[x+s]?.[y+t]||!m[x+t][y+s]){o=0;--s;break}b=s>b?s:b}b*b')
```

Try it:

```js
f=m=>eval('for(x=b=0;x<(r=m.length);++x)for(y=0;y<(c=m[0].length);++y)if(m[x][y]){for(o=s=1;o&&s<(c>r?r:c);++s)for(t=s+1;t--;)if(!m[x+s]?.[y+t]||!m[x+t][y+s]){o=0;--s;break}b=s>b?s:b}b*b')

;[
    [
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ],
    [
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ],
    [
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ],
    [
        [1]
    ],
    [
        [0]
    ]
].map(m => console.log(f(m)))
```

## JavaScript, 200 bytes

Here the complexity is much less than `O((mn)^2)` because if the algorithm find the biggest possible square it will stop

```
m=>eval('a=(c=m[0].length)>(r=m.length)?r:c;for(x=b=0;b!=a&&x<r;++x)for(y=0;b!=a&&y<c;++y)if(m[x][y]){for(o=s=1;o&&s<a;++s)for(t=s+1;t--;)if(!m[x+s]?.[y+t]||!m[x+t][y+s]){o=0;--s;break}b=s>b?s:b}b*b')
```

Try it:

```js
f=m=>eval('a=(c=m[0].length)>(r=m.length)?r:c;for(x=b=0;b!=a&&x<r;++x)for(y=0;b!=a&&y<c;++y)if(m[x][y]){for(o=s=1;o&&s<a;++s)for(t=s+1;t--;)if(!m[x+s]?.[y+t]||!m[x+t][y+s]){o=0;--s;break}b=s>b?s:b}b*b')

;[
    [
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ],
    [
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ],
    [
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ],
    [
        [1]
    ],
    [
        [0]
    ]
].map(m => console.log(f(m)))
```

### Explanation

I will not explain each line of code because it is a lot and boring

Here is illustration of algorithm:

[image]

When I meet the 1 in matrix (blue) I start checking the right and bottom edges of this cell (red cells) if all red cells are 1 then I start check the right and bottom edges of red cells (green cells) and so on until where I won't meet 0 or meet the matrix edge

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 142 bytes

```
=LET(b,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),c,TRANSPOSE(b),MAX(MMULT(N(COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(TOCOL(CELL("address",OFFSET(a,b-1,c-1)))),,,c,c),"<>1")=0),b^0))^2)
```

Input ***a*** is a *worksheet range* comprising the matrix. The above should preferably be placed in a worksheet different to that containing the matrix so as to avoid potential circular references.

Complexity is unfortunately \$\mathcal{O}(m^3)\$.